# jQuery load() with #id not working for TEXTAREA

Tags: jquery, ajax, textarea

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jQuery_ajax_load.asp

index.html:

`<textarea id="#my-textarea"></textarea>`

script.js:

`$("#my-textarea").load("db.txt");` Working

`$("#my-textarea").load("db.txt #some-data");` Not Working

`$("#my-textarea").load("db.html");` Working

`$("#my-textarea").load("db.html #some-data");` Not Working

db.txt:

`<p id="some-data">Some Data</p>Some Outside Data`

jQuery 1.11.3

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show the contents of db.txt?

Comment: `#some-data` should be a  id of a element inside  `db.txt`

Comment: db.txt:
<p id="some-data">Some Data</p>Some Outside Data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably reasons of inoperability with `textarea` somewhere deep inside the code of jQuery or/and JavaScript, but it works if you wrap your external file in `div` like this:

```
<div>
    <p id="some-data">Some data</p>
    <p id="another-some-data">Another some data</p>
    Some unwanted data
</div>
```

and use this jQuery code:

```
$.get('db.txt', function(data) {
data = $(data);
    $("#my-textarea").html($('#some-data', data).html());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a plunkr link [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/GQnIKH5OLw0W4ejqLZxa?p=preview)

```
<body>
<h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
<div id="block">here: </div>

<script>$("#block").load("db.html #some-data");</script>`
```

All I had to do was place the  tag at the end of the  tag, I don't know why it works that way.But it could be because the it loads the content before it could check for a #block id in your html.

Comment: Thank you for example. I need this for load to textarea and this not working with this tag.